# Using a single view for different data in android

Tags: android, textview

let's say that we have one edit text and one button and a single text view in an activity.

If each time I type data into the edit text and hit the button I want to get that entered data independently, example(If I type cat I want to see a cat text on the activity/ then when I enter dog I want to see also dog on the activity), the result is a ''cat text'' and beside it a ''dog text'' .

The problem : how can that be achieved using only a single text view for both data.

Answer (score 0):

onClick of button write this code:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()+ " " + editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Hey @BhaveshMisri that's not what I meant , What I need is to reuse the textview for multiple data, each data is independent of the other but all of them use the same view.

Comment: @HasanB.T Data should be independent but view should be same? That's not possible; what you can do is create a new TextView at runtime.

Comment: I dont want to add 6 textviews for 6 entered texts, I want to add into the activity only one textview for all possible values entered.

Comment: I guess it's a recyclerview thing but I dont know how it can be accomplished.

Comment: @HasanB.T yea, you can do it by recyclerView too. You haven't used it before?

Comment: I know how to implement it but I dont know how to set it in framelayout so that each view is above the other on Z-axis. And I dont know in what method I can get the text entered in edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
textView.setText("cat text");
```

use

```
textView.append("cat text");
```

it will appends the text

to goto next line then,

```
textView.append("cat text\n");
```

it will result in,

cat text

dog text

TextView can be made programaticaly

`TextView textView = new TextView(this);`

this will create a Textview Programatically.And also you can edit the properties like,

```
textView.setText("bla bla bla"); 
textView.setTextSize(...
textView.setTextColor(...
```

Comment: if let's say I want to cause (cat text ) to be dragged on touch and then I want the (dog text) to be dragged on touch, but both are independent of each other so that cat text can't be dragged when dog text is dragged.How would that be achieved.

Comment: generate the TextViews programatically.

Comment: you mean that Views (imageview, Text view.........) can be added to the activity through code.